# NSInternalInconsistencyException Invalid update: invalid number of sections 0 inserted 0 deleted

Tags: ios, uitableview, exception, tableview, uiviewanimation

My app is crashing on the line

```
 [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]
```

'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the table view after the update **(9)** must be equal to the number of sections contained in the table view before the update (0), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted **(0 inserted, 0 deleted)**.'

My update is introducing 9 new sections which consist of 19 rows all up. The rows are distributed within those 9 sections.

So from the error message, the number of section **(9)** is correct but the **(0 inserted)** not.

Any ideas what I'm missing?
I can see that my `indexPaths` that I'm building to insert in my `tableview` has the **expected 9 sections**.

Thanks!

Comment: [self.tableview reloaddata]; for refershing data(at the first time or later too) and if u r inserting row then u have to add object in NSArray and use insertRowsAtIndexPaths

Comment: I am calling reloaddata on the first load. Then as I am scrolling to load previous events, I update my tableViewData with the required objects and call insertRowsAtIndexPaths (hoping to see my rows being inserted in my tableview but it crashes)